# How to properly use AND / OR in conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query Like this:

```
SELECT AVG([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [AverageContractedAmount]
      ,MAX([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [MaxContractedAmount]
      ,MIN([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [MinContractedAmount]
FROM [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]
WHERE [DC].[ContractedAmount] != 0.00
AND [DC].[CustomerKey] = @CustomerKey
OR [A].[RegionKey] = @RegionKey
OR [A].[StateKey] = @StateKey
```

For some reason when I execute it `[MinContractedAmount]` return `0.00` value, it don't care about my where clause `[DC].[ContractedAmount] != 0.00`, why this is not working?

Note `[DC].[ContractedAmount]` is a money field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `()` for your `WHERE` clause because `AND` operator has precedence, right now interpreter understand this

```
WHERE ([DC].[ContractedAmount] != 0.00 AND [DC].[CustomerKey] = @CustomerKey)
 OR [A].[RegionKey] = @RegionKey
 OR [A].[StateKey] = @StateKey
```

You probably want

```
WHERE [DC].[ContractedAmount] != 0.00 
  AND ( [DC].[CustomerKey] = @CustomerKey
     OR [A].[RegionKey] = @RegionKey
     OR [A].[StateKey] = @StateKey )
```

Comment: Your second code snippet has two closing parentheses for only one open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how `AND` and `OR` works.

`AND` results to `TRUE` **ONLY IF ALL** involved conditions are `TRUE`

`OR` results to `TRUE` **EVEN IF JUST ONE OF** the involved conditions is `TRUE`

This explains the behavior you've noticed that one of your condition is being ignored.

**Returns `TRUE`:**

`condition1 = TRUE AND condition2 = TRUE`

**Returns `TRUE:`**

`condition1 = FALSE AND condition2 = FALSE OR condition3 = TRUE`

Solution: use parentheses to group which conditions you only need 1 result to be `TRUE`.

**Returns `FALSE`:**

`(condition1 = TRUE OR condition2 = TRUE) AND condition3 = FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you want this :

```
SELECT AVG(DC.ContractedAmount) AS AverageContractedAmount
      ,MAX(DC.ContractedAmount) AS MaxContractedAmount
      ,MIN(DC.ContractedAmount) AS MinContractedAmount
FROM DesignCustomer AS DC
WHERE DC.ContractedAmount <> 0 AND DC.CustomerKey = @CustomerKey
and exists
(
    select * 
    from Design AS D
    INNER JOIN Task AS T ON D.DesignKey = t.DesignKey
    INNER JOIN ProjectDesign AS PD ON D.DesignKey = PD.DesignKey
    INNER JOIN Project AS P ON PD.ProjectKey = P.ProjectKey
    INNER JOIN Address AS A ON A.AddressGuid = P.ProjectGuid and (A.RegionKey = @RegionKey or A.StateKey = @StateKey)
    where DC.DesignKey = D.DesignKey
)
```